Laurent series - How is the series expansion of $f_1(z)$ derived when constructing the Laurent series?
I'm reading Gamelin's Complex Analysis book and encountered a problem on Laurent series.
Suppose $f(z) = f_0(z) + f_1(z)$ is the Laurent decomposition for $f$ that is analytic  for $r < |z - z_0| < R$. Then it says that we can express $f_0(z)$ as
$$
f_0(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k (z - z_0)^k, \quad |z - z_0| < R
$$
I understand everything until here. But then it says that we can further express $f_1(z)$ as
$$
f_1(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1} a_k (z - z_0)^k, \quad |z - z_0| > r
$$
Where does this expansion of $f_1(z)$ come from?
And I'm also watching a video about this, and in the video it shows that
$$
f_1(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_k}{(z - z_0)^k} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1} a_k (z - z_0)^k, \quad |z - z_0| > r
$$
where the first equality here comes from that $f(1/z)$ is analytic for $|z - z_0| < r$. I understand why $f(1/z)$ is analytic for $|z - z_0| < r$, but how does that imply this first equality here?


But then it says that we can further express $f_1(z)$ as
$$
f_1(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1} a_k (z - z_0)^k, \quad |z - z_0| > r
$$
Where does this expansion of $f_1(z)$ come from?

Suppose $r < r'< |z - z_0| < R' < R$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be sufficiently small so that the closed disk centered at $z$ of radius $\epsilon$ lies inside the open annulus $r' < |w - z_0| < R'$. We can write $$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w - z|\, =\, \epsilon} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}\, dw = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_0} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}\, dw - \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_1} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}\, dw$$ where $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_1$ are the positively oriented circles $|w-z_0| = R'$ and $|w - z_0| = r'$, respectively. Let $$f_1(z) = -\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\Gamma_1} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}\, dw$$ and fix $w\in \Gamma_1$. Since $|w - z_0| = r' < |z - z_0|$, we can expand $$\frac{1}{w-z} = \frac{1}{(w-z_0) - (z-z_0)} = -\frac{1}{z-z_0}\sum_{k\, =\, 0}^\infty \left(\frac{w-z_0}{z-z_0}\right)^k$$ The above series converges uniformly in $\Gamma_1$, so we can integrate it against $f(w)$ term-by-term to obtain $$f_1(z) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_1} (w-z_0)^{k-1}\, dw\right]\frac{1}{(z-z_0)^k} = \sum_{k\, =\, -\infty}^{-1} a_k (z - z_0)^k$$ where $a_k = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\Gamma_1} (w - z_0)^{-k-1}\, dw$.
